# Interesting set problem

Tags: combinatorics

Having a set with all natural numbers from $1$ to $30$, you can do a very special operation: choose any subset of it and subtract from all its members certain number of your choice.For example:
It was
$$\{1,2,3,...,30\}$$ 
Operation: subtracting $7$ from $30$,$28$ and $25$. Now we have:
$$\{1,2,3,...,24,18,26,27,21,29,23\}$$
The question: what is the minimal number of operations to turn all $30$ members of this set into $0$.
I tried using some sort of "divide and conqueror" algorithm approach: first subtract $16$ from $16$ and all numbers bigger to get $\{1,2,3,...,15,0,1,2,3,..,14\}$ . Now make operation with $8$ to get $\{1,...,7,0,1,...,8,0,1,...,7,0,1,...,6\}$. And so on...
Doing this way it takes only $5$ operations and I have a good sense that $5$ is the minimal possible number.
Tried several things to prove, like tracking the sum of all numbers and looking its properties, but it didn't give me success.
I ask you to show me **as much as possible different ways** to prove that $5$ is minimal.
Please, because I am deeply convinced that a great learning happens only when the problem was seen at all different angles, points of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore a number $x$ being repeatedly applied(subtracted from) a number which was originally $y$ - if $x$ was applied $k$ times to $y$, replace it with a single operation of $kx$ on $y$. With this observation, your problem reduces to finding the smallest set, $S$, such that every number in ${1, \cdots, n}$ can be represented as the sum of a subset of $S$. Since the number of non-empty subsets of $S$ is $2^{|S|}-1$, we have $n \leq 2^{|S|}-1$. This gives $|S| \geq \lceil{\log{n+1}}\rceil$. Picking $S$ to be the set of all powers of $2$ less than $n+1$ gives us a set which achieves equality in the above bound. Thus, the answer, for any $n$, is $\lceil{\log{n+1}}\rceil$. Substituting $n=30$, you see that it indeed gives you $\lceil \log{31}\rceil = 5$.